# Java builder pattern with non-trivial subclass tree

Tags: java, generics, builder

I'm familiar with using the builder pattern with generics and subclassing, but I can't see how to make it work with a non-trivial tree of subclasses (i.e. C extends B extends A). Here's a simple example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class A {
    private final int value;

    protected A(ABuilder builder) {
        this.value = builder.value;
    }

    public int getValue() { return value; }

    public static class ABuilder<T extends ABuilder<T>> {
        private int value;

        public T withValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
            return (T) this;
        }

        public A build() {
            return new A(this);
        }
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private final String name;

    public static BBuilder builder() {
        return new BBuilder();
    }

    protected B(BBuilder builder) {
        super(builder);
        this.name = builder.name;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public static class BBuilder<U extends BBuilder<U>> extends ABuilder<BBuilder<U>> {
        private String name;

        public U withName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return (U) this;
        }

        public B build() {
            return new B(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is fine if I declare BBuilder without the generic type:

```
public static class BBuilder extends ABuilder<BBuilder>
```

Since I want BBuilder to be extended by a CBuilder, I'm trying to use the same sort of Curiously Recurring Template Pattern as ABuilder. But like this, the compiler sees BBuilder.withValue() as returning an ABuilder, not a BBuilder as I want. This:

```
    B b = builder.withValue(1)
    .withName("X")
    .build();
```

doesn't compile. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here, I've been going round trying different patterns of generics but can't get it to work.

Thanks to anyone who has any advice.

Comment: "Since I want BBuilder to be extended by a CBuilder" Why?

Comment: "*`public static class ABuilder<T extends ABuilder<T>> { ... }`*" - How would you properly define a variable of that type without subclassing and without using Raw Types? --- "*`return new BBuilder();`*" - That is a Raw Type.

Comment: Anyway.. you don't see to need any generics on this as returning the instance will always be a subclass of ABuilder

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos the problem is method chaining: if you call a method on a `BBuilder` that stems from `ABuilder`, the return type of the method will be an `ABuilder` and thus you limit the access to the methods you can call from there.

Comment: Ohh.. trues I was missing the ABuilder methods would return ABuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your mistake only with declaring correct parameter:

```
class A {

    private final int value;

    public static <T extends Builder<T>> T builderA() {
        return (T)new Builder<>();
    }

    protected A(Builder<? extends Builder<?>> builder) {
        value = builder.value;
    }

    public static class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> {

        private int value;

        public T withValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
            return (T)this;
        }

        public A build() {
            return new A(this);
        }
    }
}

class B extends A {

    private final String name;

    public static <T extends Builder<T>> T builderB() {
        return (T)new Builder<>();
    }

    protected B(Builder<? extends Builder<?>> builder) {
        super(builder);
        name = builder.name;
    }

    public static class Builder<T extends Builder<T>> extends A.Builder<T> {

        private String name;

        public Builder<T> withName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public B build() {
            return new B(this);
        }
    }
}
```

**Client code:**

```
A a = A.builder().withValue(1).build();
B b = B.builder().withValue(2).withName("xx").build();
```

Comment: That is a nice solution. Two questions: Is there any way to elimiate the casts to `T`? --- What exaclty is the inferred type of `return new Builder<>();` in the `builder()`-methods?

Comment: *Is there any way to elimiate the casts to T* - using this approach - not. Probably it could be better not to do Builder inheritance. *What exaclty is the inferred type of return new Builder<>();* - `? extends B.Builder<?>`

Comment: "*`? extends B.Builder<?>`*" - Funny thing is: if you substitude the diamond operator with this type, you will get a compiler error: `error: unexpected type ... required: class or interface without bounds ... found:    ? extends Builder<?>`.

Comment: I have checked this code before write here. I do not have any compile error or even warning. You can check it. :-) Try just copy-paste it and run in IDE. I think you're going to have the same result.

Comment: Your code is correct. But the inferred type you gave is not. As of now, I am unable to declare any type within the diamond that would compile. Only things that do compile are the diamond and a raw type. The question is not essential, it is more a curiosity on my end.

Comment: I have remove `diamonds` from `builder` method. What about this one?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173081/discussion-between-turing85-and-oleg-cherednik).

Comment: Thank @oleg.cherednik. I was concentrating so hard on the class declaration I didn't see that the problem was with the builder method

Comment: *Opinion:* This is a hack, playing havoc with type erasure. Method `builderA`: Type parameter `T` is declared to be a *subclass* of `Builder`, so casting `new Builder` to `T` should be an instantaneous `ClassCastException` at *runtime*. --- *"I do not have any compile error or even warning"* Of course not. Casting bypasses the compiler type-checking!!! That doesn't mean the code is *sane*!

Comment: @Andreas I have checked this code as well. No RuntimeError as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you need generics? This hierarchy seems to work fine without generics.

```
static class A {
    protected final int value;

    protected A(ABuilder builder) {
        this.value = builder.value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "A{" +
                "value=" + value +
                '}';
    }

    public static ABuilder builder() {
        return new ABuilder();
    }

    public static class ABuilder {
        protected int value;

        public ABuilder withValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
            return this;
        }

        public A build() {
            return new A(this);
        }
    }

}

static class B extends A {
    protected final String name;

    protected B(BBuilder builder) {
        super(builder);
        this.name = builder.name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "B{" +
                "value=" + value +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public static BBuilder builder() {
        return new BBuilder();
    }

    public static class BBuilder extends ABuilder {
        private String name;

        public BBuilder withName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public BBuilder withValue(int value) {
            this.value = value * 2;
            return this;
        }

        public B build() {
            return new B(this);
        }
    }
}

static class C extends B {
    private final String otherName;

    protected C(CBuilder builder) {
        super(builder);
        this.otherName = builder.otherName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return otherName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "C{" +
                "value=" + value +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", otherName='" + otherName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public static CBuilder builder() {
        return new CBuilder();
    }

    public static class CBuilder extends BBuilder {
        private String otherName;

        public CBuilder withName(String name) {
            this.otherName = name;
            return this;
        }

        public C build() {
            return new C(this);
        }
    }
}

public void test() {
    A a = A.builder().withValue(10).build();
    B b = B.builder().withValue(10).withName("B").build();
    C c = C.builder().withName("C").build();
    System.out.println("a = "+a);
    System.out.println("b = "+b);
    System.out.println("c = "+c);
}
```

Comment: This approach has the downside that you are forced to override all `with...(...)`-mehtods of (all your) parent class(es) and fill those methods with boilerplate code. Otherwise, method chaining will break.

Comment: @Turing85 - I don't see that. See how I have not overridden `withValue` in `C`. Perhaps you could explain further.

Comment: @Turing85 - Oh wait - I see what you mean - calling `CBuilder.withValue` returns a `BBuilder` - so not as useful I agree.