# Generic parameter: only diamond operator seems to work

Tags: java, generics, type-inference

Background: the question came up in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50839330/4216641) (the first revision of the answer, to be exact). The code presented in this question is reduced to the bare minimum to explain the problem.

Suppose we have the following code:

```
public class Sample<T extends Sample<T>> {

    public static Sample<? extends Sample<?>> get() {
        return new Sample<>();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Sample<? extends Sample<?>> sample = Sample.get();
    }
}
```

It compiles without warning and executes fine. However, if one tries to somehow define the inferred type of `return new Sample<>();` in `get()` explicitly the compiler complains.

Up until now, I was under the impression that the diamond operator is just some syntactic sugar to not write explicit types and thus could always be replaced with some explicit type. For the given example, I was not able to define any explicit type for the return value to make the code compile. Is it possible to explicitly define the generic type of the return value or is the diamond-operator needed in this case?

Below are some attempts I made to explicitly define the generic type of the returned value with the corresponding compiler errors.

---

`return new Sample<Sample>` results in:

```
Sample.java:6: error: type argument Sample is not within bounds of type-variable T
            return new Sample<Sample>();
                              ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Sample<T> declared in class Sample
Sample.java:6: error: incompatible types: Sample<Sample> cannot be converted to Sample<? extends Sample<?>>
            return new Sample<Sample>();
                   ^
```

---

`return new Sample<Sample<?>>` results in:

```
Sample.java:6: error: type argument Sample<?> is not within bounds of type-variable T
            return new Sample<Sample<?>>();
                                    ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Sample<T> declared in class Sample
```

---

`return new Sample<Sample<>>();` results in:

```
Sample.java:6: error: illegal start of type
           return new Sample<Sample<>>();
                                    ^
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you've written `public static Sample<? extends Sample<?>> get()` instead of just `public static Sample<?> get()`?  It seems to me that you've already defined `Sample` in a way that the type parameter has to extend a `Sample` of itself.  That declaration seems redundant to me, and may cause problems if you can't get the two `?` values to match.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Take a look at the mentioned answer (and its question). It came up in the context of writing builders and using inheritance between builders.

Comment: No, I feel there's nothing in the linked question that justifies adding the `extends` clause to that method signature.  Try making `get` just return a `Sample<?>`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem forget what I just wrote. It was a brain fart. You seem to be right for the concrete problem. My question still stands: is this a case where `<>` is needed?

Comment: You've bounded the type parameter `T` in `Sample` to `extends Sample<T>`.  That means that any `Sample<X>` is in fact a `Sample<X extends Sample<X>>`.  It's therefore unnecessary to write `Sample<? extends Sample<?>>` when all you mean is `Sample<?>`.  And of course, it can lead to problems where the two `?` values don't match.  So you choose - either take my advice, or continue shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem for the specific problem of the `Builder`, I take your advice ;) but this does not change the question at hand.

Comment: I think `Sample<?>` and `Sample<? extends Sample<?>>` are equivalent types. See for example https://ideone.com/XkOkZf. I can't think of a straightforward way of explaining what's going on here, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9) simply says:

> If the type argument list to the class is empty — the diamond form `<>` — the type arguments of the class are **inferred**.

So, is there some inferred `X` that will satisfy the solution? *Yes.*

Of course, for you to *explicitly* define such an `X`, you'd have to declare it:

```
public static <X extends Sample<X>> Sample<? extends Sample<?>> get() {
    return new Sample<X>();
}
```

The explicit `Sample<X>` is compatible with the return type `Sample<? extends Sample<?>>`, so compiler is happy.

The fact that return type is a messed up `Sample<? extends Sample<?>>` is an entirely different story.

Comment: As so often: If you see the solution, it is obvious. Nice answer.

Comment: That seems like a rather odd signature.  Why not simply write `public static <X extends Sample<X>> Sample<X> get()`, and let the caller decide whether `X` gets bound to a wildcard or a concrete type?

Comment: @MikeStrobel Ask [oleg.cherednik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50839330/5221149). He's the one that came up with the insane code that triggered *this* question. I'm just answering the diamond operator question posted here.

Comment: @MikeStrobel This actually results in a compile-time error since both `builder()`-methods (in `A` and `B`) will have the same erasure. The "cleanest" solution seems to be to return a `Builder<?>`.

Answer (score 8):

#### Instantiating Generics with Wildcards

There's a couple problems here, but before delving into them, let me address your actual question:

> Is it possible to explicitly define the generic type of the return value or is the diamond-operator needed in this case?

It is not possible to explicitly instantiate a `Sample<? extends Sample<?>>` (or a `Sample<?>` for that matter).  Wildcards **may not** be used as type arguments when instantiating a generic type, though they may be nested *within* type arguments.  For example, while it is legal to instantiate an `ArrayList<Sample<?>>`, you **cannot** instantiate an `ArrayList<?>`.

The most obvious workaround would be to simply return some other concrete type that is *assignable to* `Sample<?>`.  For example:

```
class Sample<T extends Sample<T>> {
    static class X extends Sample<X> {}

    public static Sample<? extends Sample<?>> get() {
        return new X();
    }
}
```

However, if you specifically want to return a generic instantiation of the `Sample<>` class containing wildcards, then you must rely on generic inference to work out the type arguments for you.  There are a few ways to go about this, but it *usually* involves one of the following:

1. Using the diamond operator, as you are doing right now.
2. Delegating to a generic method that captures your wildcard with a type variable.

While you cannot include a wildcard directly in a generic instantiation, it's perfectly legal to include a type variable, and that's what makes option (2) possible.  All we have to do is ensure that the type variable in the delegate method gets bound to a wildcard at the call site.  Every mention of the type variable the method's signature and body then gets replaced with a reference to that wildcard.  For example:

```
public class Sample<T extends Sample<T>> {
    public static Sample<? extends Sample<?>> get() {
        final Sample<?> s = get0();
        return s;
    }

    private static <T extends Sample<T>> Sample<T> get0() {
        return new Sample<T>();
    }
}
```

Here, the return type of `Sample<T> get0()` gets expanded to `Sample<WC#1 extends Sample<WC#1>>`, where `WC#1` represents a captured copy of the wildcard inferred from the assignment target in `Sample<?> s = get0()`.

#### Multiple Wildcards in a Type Signature

Now, let's address that method signature of yours. It's hard to tell for sure based on what code you've provided, but I would *guess* that a return type of `Sample<? extends Sample<?>>` is ***not*** what you really want. When wildcards appear in a type, each wildcard is **distinct from all others**. There is no enforcement that the first wildcard and second wildcard refer to the same type.

Let's say `get()` returns a value of type `X`.  If it was your intention to ensure that `X` extends `Sample<X>`, then you have failed.  Consider:

```
class Sample<T extends Sample<T>> {
    static class X extends Sample<X> {}
    static class Y extends Sample<X> {}

    public static Sample<? extends Sample<?>> get() {
        return new Y();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Sample<?> s = Sample.get(); // legal (!)
    }
}
```

In `main`, variable `s` holds a value that is a `Sample<X>` and a `Y`, but **not** a `Sample<Y>`.  Is that what you'd intended?  If not, I suggest replacing the wildcard in your method signature with a type variable, then letting the caller decide the type argument:

```
class Sample<T extends Sample<T>> {
    static class X extends Sample<X> {}
    static class Y extends Sample<X> {}

    public static <T extends Sample<T>> Sample<T> get() { /* ... */ }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Sample<X> x = Sample.get();     // legal
        Sample<Y> y = Sample.get();     // NOT legal

        Sample<?> ww = Sample.get();    // legal
        Sample<?> wx = Sample.<X>get(); // legal
        Sample<?> wy = Sample.<Y>get(); // NOT legal
    }
}
```

The version above effectively guarantees that, for some return value of type `A`, the returned value extends `Sample<A>`.  In theory, it even works when `T` is bound to a wildcard.  Why?  It goes back to *wildcard capture*:

In your original `get` method, the two wildcards could end up referring to different types.  In effect, your return type was `Sample<WC#1 extends Sample<WC#2>`, where `WC#1` and `WC#2` are separate wildcards that are not related in any way.  But in the example above, binding `T` to a wildcard *captures* it, allowing *the same wildcard* to appear in more than one spot.  Thus, when `T` is bound to a wildcard `WC#1`, the return type expands to `Sample<WC#1 extends Sample<WC#1>`.  Remember, there is no way to express that type directly in Java: it can only be done by relying on type inference.

Now, I said this works with wildcards *in theory*.  In practice, you probably won't be able to implement `get` in such a way that the generic constraints are runtime-enforceable.  That's because of *type erasure*: the compiler can emit a `classcast` instruction to verify that the returned value is, for example, both an `X` and a `Sample`, but it **cannot** verify that it's actually a `Sample<X>`, because all generic forms of `Sample` have the same runtime type.  For concrete type arguments, the compiler can usually prevent suspect code from compiling, but when you throw wildcards into the mix, complex generic constraints become difficult or impossible to enforce.  Buyer beware :).

---

#### Aside

If all this is confusing to you, don't fret: wildcards and wildcard capture are among the most difficult aspects of Java generics to understand.  It's also not clear whether understanding these will actually help you with your immediate goal.  If you have an API in mind, it might be best to submit it to the Code Review stack exchange and see what kind of feedback you get.

Comment: This seems sensible. But my question still stands: Is this something that is not expressable through an explicit type in Java and therefore forces us to use the diamond??

Comment: No, you cannot express this type directly.  You have to rely on type inference, either via the diamond operator, or by invoking a generic method and letting the wildcard get captured by a type variable.